# jQuery don't work inside PHP echo

Tags: php, jquery

Value of `$qty` is in my database. I've read few similar questions and I already added `$(document).ready` but it's still not working.

```
echo "<div class='sp-quantity'>
    <div class='sp-minus fff'><a class='ddd' href='#' data-multi='-1'>-</a></div>
    <div class='col-xs-3 sp-input'>
    <input type='text' class='quntity-input form-control qty' pid='$bookid' id='qty-$bookid' value='$qty'/>
    </div>
    <div class='sp-plus fff'><a class='ddd' href='#' data-multi='1'>+</a></div>
    </div>";        

echo "<script>";
echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
echo "$('.ddd').on('click', function() {";
echo "var $button = $(this);";
echo "var $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find('input.quntity-input');";
echo "$input.val(function(i, value) {";
echo "return +value + (1 * +$button.data('multi'));";
echo "});";
echo "});";
echo "});";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: FWIW, these days, under HTML5, you can use `type='number'` as follows -  `<input type='number' min='0' step='1' class='quntity-input form-control qty' pid='$bookid' id='qty-$bookid' value='$qty'/>` to give the input +/- controls.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your PHP & Javascript variable syntax confused. PHP uses `$` as the start of every variable name. Javascript doesn't, plus jquery uses `$` in a special way. On top of that, PHP does automatic string substitution of anything starting with a $ that can be a valid variable name as long as the string uses `"` instead of `'`. So the result of your code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ddd').on('click', function() {
      var $button = $(this);
      var $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find('input.quntity-input');
      $input.val(function(i, value) {
         return +value + (1 * +$button.data('multi'));
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

`$button` and `$input` will be substituted with the contents of the PHP variables of those names. I suspect that's not what you want - though I have done things like that at times myself. What I think you want is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ddd').on('click', function() {
      var button = $(this);
      var input = button.closest('.sp-quantity').find('input.quntity-input');
      input.val(function(i, value) {
         return +value + (1 * + button.data('multi'));
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Two other suggestions:

1 - If you have absolutely no PHP values within a bunch of Javascript (or plain HTML) echo lines, you can exit out of PHP code mode by using `?>` and not use `echo` and avoid any issues of string substitution.

2 - Personally, I prefer using `{$string}` for my variables inside strings as it makes the substitution more obvious and sometimes less ambiguous.

Comment: Perfectly valid using `$` as character in javascript variable. In fact it is very common practice to prefix variables that are jQuery objects with `$`

Comment: Yes it is OK, I didn't mean it **can't** be that way, just that in PHP it **must** be that way whereas in Javascript it is optional. But mixing the 2 - i.e., when spitting out Javascript code inside PHP " strings - is messy.

Comment: it's working but I don't understand why the value is added by 2 not 1. supposingly it should be one.example the value of $qty in database is 1 but if  click + sign it become 3.

Comment: Okay I found my mistake. Now it's working fine.. thanks

Comment: And what was your mistake? All these rampant + signs? ;)